# Flutter: TextField_How can I make TextField not foucs when I long-press it?

Tags: flutter

I'm developing an application that has to reorder some elements when I long press it and drag-drop it.
Some of the elements has TextField, so when I long press that Element(to reorder with other elements), the TextField is on focus and keyboard appears.
I want to make TextField on focus only on tap, not on longPress.
Can I make it possible?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

first wrap the textfield in GestureDetector, then try like this.you can change the logic according to need.

```
bool isFocused = false; // global bool value

               GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {

                setState(() {
                  isFocused = true;
                });

              },
              onLongPress: () {
                setState(() {
                  isFocused = false;
                });
              },
              child: TextFormField(
                readOnly: isFocused,
              ))
```

Comment: What is this syntax ??

Comment: @gruvw which syntax you are talking about?the code? its dart code

Comment: `readOnly: true` in a function

Comment: This does not work either... how would the textfield know that this value changed as it is nested inside the gesture detector... You don't have access to the readOnly property here.